# How is this Plunkr code working?

Tags: angular

What is the scope of the variable/expression when used in `[]` in Angular? In the following Plunkr code, `helloWorld` is defined in `rio-app` but is used in `rio-hello`. Would Angular search all the way up to root parent to find a variable? What would happen if both child and parent component have the same variable? I added `helloName: string = "test";` in `hello.component.ts` but the output was not `Hello test`

http://plnkr.co/edit/LEtEN9?p=preview

```
<div>
  <rio-hello name="World"></rio-hello> 
  <rio-hello [name]="helloName"></rio-hello>
</div>
```

Changed `hello.component.ts` but still got the same output.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rio-hello',
  template: '<p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>',
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  helloName: string = "test";

}
```

Comment: When you use `[name]`, you're supposed to give a variable name or a string like `"'something'"`, but when you use it as an attribute you can provide a string without the extra quotes like `name="something"`

Comment: Isn't that what I am already doing? In `[name]="helloName"`, `helloName` is defined in `HelloComponent` (by me to try out scenario where multiple components have same property) and also in `app.component.ts` (in the original plunkr code)

Comment: @ManuChadha Actually when you set `[name]="helloName"` you are overriding the `name` value in the `component` that's why you will always get the same output, take a look at [**my answer** below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47810954/3669624) for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `rio-app` contains the two `rio-hello` ?

If so, here is how it works :

Firt, in the `app` component, you have a variable called `helloName`.

In the corresponding HTML, you see 2 `hello` components :

```
<rio-hello name="World"></rio-hello>
<rio-hello [name]="helloName"></rio-hello>
```

Then, in the `hello` component, you have this :

```
@Input() name: string;
```

This line says

> On the HTML selector of my component, there is an attribute called name. Please take its value and return it to me.

What happens is that your `hello` component will take the value of the attribute, and set it in a variable. But how it decides what to take ? Because we seee that both components have a `name` attribute, but not written the same.

This has to do with the **Angular template syntax** : made simple it goes like this :

- `name="x"` : you send a **string equal to "x"** to the child component
- `[name]="x"` : you send a **variable called x, containing anything**, to your component
- `(name)="x($event)"` : **your child component sends a value to its parent, which is calling the function `x`**
- `[(name)]="x"` : **the parent sends an x variable to the child, which can update the value of x in the parent** (requires some more code)

I think this should explain how it works. But if not, feel free to ask !

Comment: Thanks. Understood the difference between `name="x"` and `[name]="x".` If I declare `helloName` in `rio-hello` as well (in addition to `rio-app`, i.e. `helloName: string = "test", why does the output still show `hello helloWorld` and not `hello test`?

Comment: It has something to do with your `hello` component HTML : look at it, you see `template: '<p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>',`. Simply replace name with helloName !

Comment: sorry, it is still not clear. In the original plunkr code. `<rio-hello [name]="helloName"></rio-hello>` means that evaluate "helloName" as an expression and assign the value to `name`. So Angular finds `helloName` property in `rio-app` and assigns it to `name` of `rio-hello`. Now if I define the same property in `rio-hello` as well (without removing it from `rio-app`), why isn't Angular picking `helloName` from `rio-hello`?

Comment: Because **you see what the HTML wants to show you**. In the HTML, there is the code `{{ name }}`. It means `please replace this code with the content of the variable name`. Thus, if you want to display the content of the second `helloName`, you need to replace `{{name}}` with `{{helloName}}` !

Comment: I do not want to display content of `helloName`. I am experimenting that if a variable with same name (`helloName="test`) is defined in a component (`rio-hello="hello Other"`) as well as in its parent (`rio-app`), why does Angular pick the value of parent and not own component.

Comment: I know you don't want, I'm explaining to you why Angular doesn't pick the value. You **have to tell him to pick the correct value**. Just creating a variable won't do anything, you have to tell him to use it ! You pay have created a `helloName` variable, but the `Input` is still bound to `name`. So your variable does absolutely nothing, because either you didn't put it in the HTML, or you didn't change the Input binding.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying hard to understand but am still unable to. Probably we are not discussing the same thing. The problem for me is not that `Input is still bound to name`. I am happy that the `name` is being displayed in the html. My question is that in `[name]="helloName", why does Angular use `helloName` from `rio-app` and not from `rio-hello` if `helloName` is defined in both the components.

Comment: I might have got it now. If I define `private helloName1 = "manu";` in `rio-hello` and change code in `app.component.ts` to `<rio-hello [name]="helloName1"></rio-hello>`, nothing gets printed. It seems that angular looks for `helloName1` in context of calling component `AppComponent` and not the component which actually being rendered (`HelloComponent`). Am I correct?

Comment: Oh I see your issue now (sorry, was eating). Angular is using the value of `helloName` because **you're in the HTML of the parent component**. If you create a variable in `hello` component, you create a variable in **the child component**. You see, Angular **associates a Typescript class to an HTML template**. You can't bind a second template to a class, or a second class to a template ! (Well, you can, but since you start, just assume that). That's why your value doesn't change : **you create a variable in the wrong component**

Answer (score 0):

`[name]` expects a variable

`name` is an attribute that expects a string, you can't use variables here

For example, try using
`<rio-hello name="helloName"></rio-hello>`

Although `helloName` is a variable, Angular considers it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `name` variable is local to the `rio-hello` component, so whenever you include that component in your app it will hold each own `name` variable.

So in the code:

```
<div>
  <rio-hello name="World"></rio-hello> 
  <rio-hello [name]="helloName"></rio-hello>
</div>
```

There are two `rio-hello` components and each one has its own `name` variable binded respectively with `name="World"` and `[name]="helloName"`.

And to answer your second question:

> Changed hello.component.ts but still got the same output.

Actually when you bind the `name` value in the HTML via:

```
<rio-hello [name]="helloName"></rio-hello>
```

It will override the initialized value of `nae` in :

```
@Input() name: string;
```